# Is there a way in Python to find a file with the smallest number in its name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of documents created by one script that are all called like this:

```
name_*score*
```

`*score*` is a float and I need in another script to identify the file with the smallest number in the folder. Example:

```
name_123.12
name_145.45
```

This should return string "name_123.12"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) takes a key function. You can use that to define the way `min` is calculated:

```
files = [
    "name_123.12",
    "name_145.45",
    "name_121.45",
    "name_121.457"
]

min(files, key=lambda x: float((x.split('_')[1])))

# name_121.45
```

Comment: Is not OP having trouble with finding the smallest number file from an actual directory of files (though the approach would be the same)?

Comment: @Austin I changed the files list to a list of all of my files and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to say Mark Meyer is completely right on this one, but you also mentioned that you were reading these file names from a directory. In that case, there is a bit of code you could add to Mark's answer:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/path/to/directory")
files = glob.glob("*")

print(min(files, key=lambda x: float((x.split('_')[1]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try get the number part first, and then convert it to float and sort.
for example:

```
new_list = [float(name[5:]) for name in YOURLIST] # trim out the unrelated part and convert to float
result = 'name_' + str(min(new_list)) # this is your result
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to get the lowest value by providing a directory.

```
import os
import re
import sys

def get_lowest(directory):
    lowest = sys.maxint
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        match = re.match(r'name_\d+(?:\.\d+)', filename)
        if match:
            number = re.search(r'(?<=_)\d+(?:\.\d+)', match.group(0))
            if number:
                value = float(number.group(0))
                if value < lowest:
                    lowest = value
    return lowest

print(get_lowest('./'))
```

Expanded on Tim Biegeleisen's answer, thank you Tim!